# How to POST these variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script called *New script* is suppose to output 2 integer variables `anchor` and `signed`.

I would like to replace *Old script* with *New script*, but as you can see, they are very different.

**Question**

How do I submit/post `anchor` and `signed` in *New script*?

**New script**

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('form').delegate('input:submit', 'click', function() {
        var anchor = this.name;
        var checkboxState = $('#' + anchor).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');

        var signed = 0;
        if (checkboxState == true) {
            signed = 1;
        }

        alert(anchor + ' ' + signed);

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Old script**

```
// sends the form content to server side, and stay on page
$('form').live('submit', function() {

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        // do something here on success
    }, 'json');

    // don't redirect
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/receiver.pl" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Put this</strike>

```
$.post($(this).prop('action'), {anchor: anchor, signed: signed}, function(response) {
   // do something here on success
}, 'json');
```

in place of alert

Here is the proper one, and running ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/pJgyu/16539/

Comment: When I try that I can see that the script is executed then one of the submit buttons are pressed, but the server-side script `<form action="/cgi-bin/receiver.pl" method="post">` is not being executed. Do you have an idea where the problem could be? I have multiple submit buttons in the same `<form>`.